# Wordpress not loading javascript file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, ftp

I have just uploaded a wordpress site from previously developing it on my localhost. On my localhost there are several plugin javascript files that are picked up and used to display a tooltip on the google map plugin for the markers.

On my localhost this all works fine but when i uploaded this through FTP, some of the javascript files appear to longer be loaded. Is there any way to check which files are being uploaded when the page is loading the javascript?

Whenever i try to check or edit the file from Filezilla, it gives a Microsoft JScript runtime error, Code: 800A1391, Error: 'document' is undefined, so i can't check that what the host uses is the exact same code as my localhost.

Many thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Most browser developer toolkits (Dragonfly, Chrome Developer Tools, Firebug, etc) include a **Net** tab which will tell you which files have been requested and the status of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using either firebug http://getfirebug.com/ with Firefox or the Chrome web inspector and look at the (Net/Network) panel while you reload the page to see if the js files are trying to load. This should give you some insight.